# Method for quickly finding folder paths given many network share names (Windows)

Tags: windows, network-share

I am currently analyzing the locations of thousands of home directories in my organization. I have run a script that spits out each user along with their home directory (share name) into a csv.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=org,DC=com" -Filter * -Property * |
    Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName,homeDirectory|
        Export-CSV -Path C:\homedirs.csv
```

Either by revising this script or operating on the resulting file, how can I produce the same result, but with each share replaced with the actual path it represents?

Also know that these shares are located across multiple servers.

Edit: It looks like the information returned by
`wmic /node:<servernames> share` could be useful for checking against the list of share names I already have, but how can I tie this in?

Comment: With actual path, do you mean each shares local path on its respective server?

Comment: Yes. We want to know where each user's files are sitting exactly so that we can clean everything up.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about the task in a fashion similar to this:

1. Get the data from AD into a hashtable.
2. Loop, read the full share path (and the other fields too, to be able to print them into a new csv).
3. From the path break out the servername from the sharename using the [split method](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.se/2009/08/string-manipulation-splitting-and.html).
4. Use the `get-wmiobject` cmdlet to [call the server and get the local path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739072/local-path-from-shared-path-powershell) using the servername and sharename extracted in the previous step.
5. As a suggestion only, output the full share path, the server, the sharename and the local sharepath to a new csv file (i.e. store all the stuff you extracted from the original file in case you find another use for it).
6. Loopback

This could then be optimized, for instance by calling each unique server once and executing all share queries for that server locally in a batch (using `invoke-command` for example, and/or running as `workflow` to process multiple servers in parallel).

**[EDIT] Here is a concrete example based on the steps above.**

*Input for the homedir is expected to be in the form \\servername\sharename\subdir*

*When processing I chose to be interested only in \\servername\sharename*

*Output I choose to be sAMAccountName;homeDirectory;ServerName;ShareName;ShareLocalPath*

Depending on what you're after you need to tweak this, naturally.

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$Cred = Get-Credential
$CsvFile = 'E:\temp49\homedirs2.csv'

# Read the data from AD into a hashtable.
if ($HashTable) {Remove-Variable HashTable}
$HashTable = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property sAMAccountName, homeDirectory |
Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName, homeDirectory

# Iterate through the hashtable.
$HashTable | ForEach-Object `
{
  # Only process if the home directory has a value.
  if (-not($_.homeDirectory -eq $null)) `
  {
    # Convert the homedir and samaccountname into strings and store in variables.
    [string]$homeDirectory = $_.homeDirectory
    [string]$sAMAccountName = $_.sAMAccountName

    # Extract the servername and the sharename from the homedirectory path.
    [array]$homeDirectorySplit = $homeDirectory -Split [regex]::Escape(‘\’)
    $ServerName = $homeDirectorySplit[2]
    $ShareName = $homeDirectorySplit[3]
    # ...If more levels are needed just keep going.

    # Call the server to get the shares local path.
    $ShareLocalPath = ((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ServerName `
                      -Credential $Cred Win32_Share) |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Name -eq $ShareName }).Path

    # Print to a semicolon delimited file.
    "$sAMAccountName;$homeDirectory;$ServerName;$ShareName;$ShareLocalPath" |
    Out-File $CsvFile -NoClobber -Append
  }
}
```

If this was a serious endeavour I would add logging and error checking. I would optimize server calls as suggested above and ping each server before calling it using `Test-Connection`. I would finally look at achieving parallel processing if the servers were very numerous, all in the name of reliability, resource conservation and speed of execution.